# rails controllers/forms - where to build nested models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

In my Rails app, I have a few forms that accept nested models for new objects.  So for example:

```
class Maker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :maker
end
```

Before I show that form though, I need to build some of the nested models for my Maker model, or they don't show in the form.  E.g.:

```
maker = Maker.new
3.times do
  maker.cars.build
end
```

But where should this code ideally go?  In the model as its own `form_display` function, in the controller, in a decorator, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to this question will be somewhat opinion-based. From a separation-of-concerns standpoint, if you're already using decorators in your project it might make more sense to put the logic there than in the controller or the model.

```
# maker_decorator.rb
def cars
  if object.new_record? && object.cars.none?
    3.times { object.cars.build }
  end

  object.cars
end
```

If you don't want to deal with decorators, putting the logic in the controller seems a reasonable approach (as long as it's not being duplicated across multiple actions).

```
# makers_controller.rb
def new
  @maker = Maker.new
  3.times { @maker.cars.build }
end
```

I wouldn't add model code to handle this functionality since that's a rather blatant mixing of model and view concerns, though any use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will tend to push you down that route. "Form objects" avert this problem, though that might be a heavyweight solution in your case and there are few established libraries or conventions for this pattern at the moment ([see #3 in this blog post](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)).